# MVC Add Multiple Entries to Database with one action

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am attempting to enter new entries into a table called `EmployeeCourseStatus` when another table `Course` has been edited.

Whenever a `Course` entry is edited to increase its Revision by 1, I need it to update the `EmployeeCourseStatus` so it will keep the previous course history for each employee and add a duplicate entry with the new revision number.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CourseID,CourseName,SiteID,ValidFor,Rev,EffectiveDate,ExpiredDate")] Course course, EmployeeCourseStatu employeeCourseStatu,CourseViewModel courseViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var OringinalRev = db.Courses.AsNoTracking().Where(P => P.CourseID == course.CourseID).Select(e => e.Rev)?.FirstOrDefault();

            if (course.Rev == OringinalRev + 1)
            { 
                foreach (var item in db.EmployeeCourseStatus.Where(e => e.CourseID==course.CourseID))
                {
                    employeeCourseStatu.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
                    employeeCourseStatu.CourseID = item.CourseID;
                    employeeCourseStatu.Status = null;
                    employeeCourseStatu.ValidFor = item.ValidFor;
                    employeeCourseStatu.CompletionDate = null;
                    employeeCourseStatu.Rev = item.Rev + 1;
                    db.EmployeeCourseStatus.Add(employeeCourseStatu);
                }
            }

            db.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.SiteID = new SelectList(db.Sites, "SiteID", "SiteName", course.SiteID);
        return View(course);
    }
```

The Code above only saves one entry to the database, which I understand as I am replacing the values each time I'm looping through the table.

How can I have it so it adds each iteration to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each iteration you use the same employeeCourseStatu instance, so your list contains the same object. Every time you change its properties they are overwritten. You need to instantiate a new object in the loop e.g.

```
var ecs = new EmployeeCourseStatu();
```